# OpenLayers 7, Angular - How to show GeoTIFF on map at right location?

Tags: openlayers, geotiff-tiff, typescript

In OpenLayers 7, I am trying to show the content of a GeoTIFF file on a map within an Angular 14 Web application. Even though I am able to create a layer out of the GeoTIFFSource without error, the layer doesn't show at all and only the base map remains. I have tried many solutions, including ones shown in OpenLayers doc, without success.

Notes:

- The GeoTIFF uses the same projection as the basemap (EPSG:4326)
- The file imagery is basically a heatmap in the shape of a building
- The Geolocation is somewhere on the western part of Montreal island
- The Geolocation is not aligned with OpenStreetMap as it is a test file.
- When opened in QGIS, the file renders as such:

  [image]

Here's the TIFF file used: [sendanywhe.re/T2QFUYS1](https://sendanywhe.re/T2QFUYS1)

[Here's a stackblitz of my current progress.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-adhbzh?file=src/app/openlayers-map/openlayers-map.component.ts)

Here's the code to create the base map:

```
const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'mapnode',
  view: new View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

this.map = map;
```

And here's the code to generate the layer:

```
    const source = new GeoTIFF({
      sources: [
        {
          url: '/assets/bleh.tiff',
          min: 0,
          max: 16000,
          nodata: 0,
        },
      ],
      normalize: true,
      sourceOptions: {
        allowFullFile: true,
      }
    });

    const layer = new TileLayer({
      source: source
    })

    this.map?.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: The stackblitz demo show a CORS error. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: @JakobMiksch fetching the file is not the main issue. Stackblitz won't let me upload tiff to assets folder.

Comment: BUMP!! similar issue here, any progress on this? `gdalinfo` output would help. In my case, I suspect that it has to do with the size dimension of the file (<256x256) and/or the data type. Mine doesn't show in OpenLayers.